# VPN client configuration on Windows using a config file

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp

Is it possible to create a configuration or batch file that will initiate a VPN connection using the built-in Windows PPTP client? I want to build a scripted method that all my external users can use to avoid configuration issues.

I'm aware of `rasdial.exe` but that only lets you initiate a preconfigured connection.

I also know about the CMAK (Connection Manager Administration Kit) for Windows Servers that generates an EXE, but that doesn't suit me because I want to hand-tune the configuration to get some DNS/SMB issues sorted out, and also the CMAK for SBS2003 doesn't work on Windows 7 64 bit at least so it isn't portable enough for me. We don't have access to a more recent server OS.

EDIT: There is only one VPN, hopefully the configuration will be pretty simple but I also need to mount and unmount a network share. I can't configure their connections myself because a) I don't have access to their PCs remotely or otherwise,  b) I'm not providing tech support to the users, just giving them VPN access so I want to keep this as simple as possible, and c) I want to get a single tested configuration that just works. I would like to write a script or set of files that I email to a user with limited installation instructions. Many unis have something similar for students but using something like a preconfigured install of the Cisco client, I want to use the built-in client if possible but if an alternative client works then that would be great.

Comment: I really don't understand the question or what you are trying to do. Are they randomly connecting to various VPN's? Why wouldn't you pre-configure their RAS connections? Are you looking for something that will build these RAS connections in bulk?

Comment: @KCotreau thanks, I've added some more info to the question

Comment: Found some links that might help, will test this further: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125393 http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29&utm_content=Google+Reader looks like a combination of `rasdial/rasphone`, `netsh` and `net use` may be needed

Answer (score 0):

Specify your own custom Phone Book File is one option I use and it works very well. Custom Config File is easy and simple.

```
rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/domain:<domain>] [/phone:<phonenumber>] [/callback:<callbacknumber>] [/phonebook:<phonebookfile>] [/PrefixSuffix]
```

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff859533(v=ws.11)